# Identify indexPath for subclassed UITableViewCell so i can specify the alignment of my UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am subclassing uitableviewcell so that i can apply a standard background and text for all my cells, this is my first attempt at this but I have it mostly displaying how i would like. Although i am stuck on one issue. My table has two groups and i would like the first group to have the text centered and i would like to have the second group align to the left. But no such luck at this point.

**CustomCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];
NSLog(@"%i", indexPath);
int rows = [(UITableView *)self.superview numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
NSLog(@"%i", rows);

if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {

    if (centerText) {
        cellText = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, self.bounds.size.width - 10, 30)] autorelease];
        cellText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }else {
        cellText = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 15, self.bounds.size.width - 10, 30)] autorelease];
        cellText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    }

    cellText.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    cellText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellText.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
    cellText.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
    cellText.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x4c/255.0 green:0x4e/255.0 blue:0x48/255.0 alpha:1.0];



    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"odd_slice.png"];
    imgView.image = img;
    self.backgroundView = imgView;
    [imgView release];

    UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"content_arrow.png"];
    UIImageView *accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:accessoryImage];
    //  accessoryView.image = accessoryImage;
    self.accessoryView = accessoryView;
    [accessoryView release];


    //Selected State
    UIImage *selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"row_selected.png"];
    UIImageView *selectionView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    selectionView.image = selectionBackground;
    self.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;
    [selectionView release];

    //Adds Text
        [self addSubview:cellText];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**TableView.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CoCoachAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *keys = [[appDelegate rowersDataStore] allKeys];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            [cell setCenterText:YES];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell setCenterText:NO];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        [cell.cellText setText:@"Create New Rower"];            
        break;
    case 1:
        [cell.cellText setText:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
    // Set up the cell...
    return cell;
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how reusable cells work. When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you're getting back a cell that was already allocated. It could have been used for either group in your code.

This is the code that makes no sense:

```
if (cell == nil) {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            [cell setCenterText:YES];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell setCenterText:NO];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

You're fetching a cell. If it doesn't exist, then you set the centering (which does nothing; remember, `cell` is `nil`). You then create one.

But what you really mean to do is to set the centering *after* you've fetched or created the cell. You don't care how you get it; you just want to reconfigure it for the current values.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        [cell setCenterText:YES];
        [cell.cellText setText:@"Create New Rower"];            
        break;
    case 1:
        [cell setCenterText:NO];
        [cell.cellText setText:[keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  quick question, when when i put `cell.cellText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;` into the `case 0:` does it center the the first section, but also the 8th cell in the second section? The cell is off screen but when i scroll to it is centered. Any thoughts?

Comment: You haven't overridden `setCenterText:` to adjust the cell. Remember, they're reused. The init method doesn't get called repeatedly. So the call to `setCenterText:` sets a boolean and then is ignored by your code.